# how to delete all lines containing less than 3 letters before " : " in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors, text-editing, notepad

i want to delete all the lines containing less than 3 letters in the username
before or after any other characters but i don't need anything change in the password that's why i say before " : "

Full Example File Containing:

```
@user1example:keepline6
~!@#$%^&*(1)_+:deleteline1
..........:deleteline2
[45364\H]..;".:deleteline3
t!esting.1:keepline9
...+++#$29:deleteline4
5666D6666X67:deleteline32
namestart:keepline0
..............:deleteline8
____________:deleteline7
~!@#$%^&*()+=_-[]{}\/';.<>,:deleteline11
1start$go2deep_:keepline20
#(gold2bestar):keepline15
%%....^\/~`"':deleteline50
...e...y%%..~@:deleteline14
A``!!!!236g...:deleteline17
username9example1:5password0example1
554425$%^921:deleteline18
+++++++++++++++++:deleteline74
use123:keepline100
.....E_______:deleteline43
!!!!!!!!!!!P:deleteline47
Dy!!..,,(_)*&:deleteline49
&####...$,,,,,FW:deleteline66
4644848We:deleteline84
Zx5654644889:deleteline96
21Gt:deleteline89
@dF.:deleteline67
username@gmail.com:password12
¥5G5Y.....:deleteline94
user@yahoo.com:password1
```

Need Result:

```
@user1example:keepline6
t!esting.1:keepline9
namestart:keepline0
1start$go2deep_:keepline20
#(gold2bestar):keepline15
username9example1:5password0example1
use123:keepline100
username@gmail.com:password12
user@yahoo.com:password1
```

Comment: -1 for using upper case letters in each word, please change it. Also it's unclear what do you mean by "this split", please post some positive examples for each of your criteria.

Comment: i mean this " : " between the username and password for example
username:password
i want to edit the username
and sorry i will change it

Comment: now its fine O.o ?

Comment: I still don't understand it:(. Again: "please post some positive examples for each of your criteria", not just post your expected output, but also give example of lines to be deleted explaining why it need to be deleted.

Comment: because i want to keep only the lines containing username:password
with the username not less than 3 letters on it and the rest deleted
and most of the lines in my file have many of that kind what i just show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){0,2}[^a-z:]*:.*\R|^[^:]{0,2}:.*\R|^[^:]*:.{0,2}\R`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
  (?:           : start non capture group
    [^a-z]*     : 0 or more any character that is not a letter
    [a-z]       : a letter
  ){0,2}        : group is repêated up to 2 times
  [^a-z:]*      : 0 or more character that is not letter or :
  :             : literally :
  .*            : 0 or more any character
  \R            : any kind of line break

 |              : OR

^               : begining of line
  [^:]{0,2}     : 0 up to 2 character that is not :
  :             : literally :
  .*            : 0 or more any character
  \R            : any kind of line break

 |              : OR

^               : begining of line
  [^:]*         : 0 or more character that is not :
  :             : literally :
  .{0,2}        : up to 2 any character
  \R            : any kind of line break
```

- DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`

**Result for given example:**

```
@user1example:keepline6
t!esting.1:keepline9
namestart:keepline0
1start$go2deep_:keepline20
#(gold2bestar):keepline15
username9example1:5password0example1
use123:keepline100
username@gmail.com:password12
user@yahoo.com:password1
```

Comment: @DeathRival: You're welcome, glad it helps.